# Passing params without nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, search, parameters

I want to pass the value of a form to a Controller that should call a method from the Model for searching products.

I want to pass the `category_id` and the string that the user writes at the `textfield`.
I would pass to the model even the blank value of params (if the user doesn't write something on the search bar or choose none category)
I want to save even the blank value cause in the model, the SQL blank variable take "all" things.
And this is good a cause if there is something in the params , the SQL will find that thing, BUT if there is nothing in the params, the SQL will take all products.

I'm not able to save the value of params in varibiles cause if params is blank it returns to me this error:

undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

I hope you understand me and what I want to do.
In other words , I want to use a simple assignment to pass a value (even blank values) to a model to do a SQL query. In one shoot of code I want to program two cases.

Here my code.

In my Controller:

...

```
if params[:search]
    @search_name = params[:search]
end

if params[:category][:name]
    @category = params[:category][:name]
end 

@products = Product.search(@search_name,@category)
```

...

In my Model:

```
def self.search(search_name,category)
    ricerca = Product.where("category_id = ? ",category)
    ricerca = ricerca.where("title like ? ", "%#{search_name}%") 
end
```

Comment: there's a better way of doing this : https://github.com/charly/siphon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get category parameters by defining a method like,

```
def category_params
  params.fetch(:category, {})
end
```

And, then look up for Products by,

```
@search_name = params[:search]
@category = category_params[:name]
@products = Product.search(@search_name, @category)
```

In my opinion, if you are making a direct query on Product, then you should do like,

```
def product_params
  params.fetch(:product, {})
end

@category = product_params[:category_id]
@title = product_params[:title]
@products = Product.search(@category, @title)
```

And in product model,

```
def self.search(category, title)
  where("category_id = ? AND title LIKE ?", category, "%#{title}%")
end
```

Comment: @Vito take note of how Yogesh got rid of some reduncies:
- the "if params[x]" clause around your assignments doesn't really do anything, since the variable will be nil anyways as soon as you call it unitialized, so you are basically saying "if this is nil, then assign nil to @thingy".
- you are calling "Product.where" in your Product model in a class method. Since you already are in the right namespace, you can just call "where"
- Yogeshs where clause will return what you want in a single database hit, instead of splitting it into two queries

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@search_name = params[:search]
@category = (params[:category].blank? ? nil : params[:category][:name])

@products = Product.search(@search_name,@category)
```

Comment: Hi Joshua! Unlucky it doesn't work. Cause @category doesn't save ' ' blank string if there isn't nothing in params[:category][:name] and then, in the first time i enter in the page (these things are in the index method) there is a strange error.  I edit your code but it still doen't work

Answer (score 0):

@Vito, change the line -> @category = params[:category][:name]  in your controller **by**

### @category = params[:category].present? ? params[:category][:name]

the issue is when you don't select the category then params[:category] comes nil and you are fetching name from params[:category] that's why error "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass" is comming.

Hope this will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

i still have problems , cause when i wrote

```
    if params[:category]
        @category = params[:category][:name]
    else
        @category = " "
    end

    if params[:search]
        @nome_ricerca = params[:search]
    else
        @nome_ricerca = " "
    end

    @products = Product.search(@nome_ricerca,@category)
```

i have this problem:

Showing C:/Bitnami/depot/app/views/store/index.html.erb where line #18 raised: 
undefined method `name' for "":String

Extracted source (around line #18):

```
 <p>
    <%= label_tag :search, 'Search:' %>
   <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= collection_select :category, :name, Category.all, :id, :name, {:prompt => 'All Categories'} %>
   <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
 </p>
```

what is this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i fixed the problem
it was (i think) concerning the fact that i used @category as variable name
maybe the view gets in confusion for this
i call @category in @cat and the problem disappears

But , now the problem is that the SQL query doesn't return all the category if i pass "" in the variable @cat
How can i have all the result of a query? with like %% it works but with
category_id = ""  no. why?

I post the code fixed for others:

In Controller:

```
if params[:category]
        @cat = params[:category][:name]
    else
        @cat = ''
    end


    if params[:search]
        @nome_ricerca = params[:search]
    else
        @nome_ricerca = ''
    end

    @products = Product.search(@nome_ricerca,@cat)
```

In model:

```
def self.search(nome_ricerca,categoria)

    ricerca = Product.where("title like ? AND category_id = ? ", "%#{nome_ricerca}%",categoria) 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

LAST POST:

PROBLEM FIXED:

In Controller

```
    @stringa_sql = ""

    if params[:search]
        @nome_ricerca = params[:search]
    else
        @nome_ricerca = ''
    end

    @stringa_sql = "title like "+"'%"+@nome_ricerca+"%'"

    if params[:category]
        if params[:category][:name] != ""
            @cat = params[:category][:name]
            @stringa_sql += " AND category_id = "+@cat
        else
            @cat = ''
        end
    end

    @products = Product.search(@stringa_sql)
```

In Model:

```
def self.search(stringa_sql)
    ricerca = Product.where(stringa_sql) 

end
```

Question: does this solution suffer Sql Injection ?

Thx all :)
I Hope this solution will help someone.